# typeof body changes from string to undefined when placed in a conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

The last `if` block does not take in the value of the body variable and converts it to `undefined`. The console log before the block shows the type of the variable is `"string"` but somehow in the condition and statement of the conditional the body turns to `undefined`.

```js
doc = doc.map(el => {
        let { title, body, _id, likes } = el
        if (title && title.length > 20) {
          el = {
            ...el,
            title:`${title.slice(0, 20)}...`,
          }
        } else if (!title || typeof title === 'undefined') {
          el = {
            ...el,
            title: '',
          }
        }
        console.log(typeof body)
        if (body.length > 55) {
          el = {
            ...el,
            body: `${body.slice(0, 55)}...`,
          }
        }
        title = el.title
        body = el.body
        console.log(typeof body)
        return {_id,title,body,likes}
      })
```

The terminal output of the logs is as follows:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
App running on port 5000...
string
undefined
string
undefined
string
undefined
```

The three different results represent three different documents in the doc array and hence the six console log outputs pertaining to each body value and its change.
I do not use semicolons in javascript, could it be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Not related to the question, but `|| typeof title === 'undefined'` is redundant. Undefined is falsey, so `!title` will be true.

Comment: Does this only happen when `body.length > 55`?

Comment: Can you simplify this to a [mcve]? All the async code that's used to access the model seems to be irrelevant, we just need to start with the value of `doc`.

Comment: Yeah so the doc is an array of document objects each having `_id, title, body` and so on fields. When sending the data to the user I need to trim the data e.g. `body.length>55` etc. As soon as it hits the last nested if block, `body` is given as undefined.

Comment: `>55` is not relevant, the number is subjective. Thanks for letting know about the `typeof` operator

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I just wanted to know if the problem only occurs when you trim the body, or does it happen all the time?

Comment: Inside `if (body.length > 55)` why don't you just try reassigning `body` to the sliced value? You've got a lot going on there with destructuring / templating / etc, and I don't think you need to reassign `el` at that point, so maybe simplify and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mLfz5c47/5/

Comment: I didn't find why it does not work, but I found another solution to the problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea why the earlier code didn't work but this much smaller code seems to do the trick

```
doc = doc.map(el => {
        let { title, body, _id, likes } = el
        body = `${body.slice(0, 55)}...`
        if (title && title.length > 20) {
          title=`${title.slice(0, 20)}...`
        } else if (!title || typeof title === 'undefined') {
          title= '...'
        }
        return {_id,title,body,likes}
      })
```

It works because of the fact that I don't need to check if the length of body is greater than 55, since a smaller value will always restore to its original size. So I trim the body first and then the title.

Thanks to anyone who helped! Will still like to find the error/ problem with earlier code.